# How to custom the delete item from ECB Menu?

Tags: contextmenu, sharepoint-2013

I want to custom the delete item message and add some action like call WCF methode.

How can I custom the message and where can I add my new action?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many article say we have to modify core.js but there are other solution, you can add to your view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Custom_AddListMenuItems(m, ctx) {
    var strDelete = "Delete API";
    var imgDelete = '';
    var strDeleteAction = "deleteThisSelectedListItem();";
    CAMOpt(m, strDelete, strDeleteAction, imgDelete);
    CAMSep(m);

   return true;       
}

function deleteThisSelectedListItem() {

    if (!IsContextSet())
        return;
    var ctx = currentCtx;
    var ciid = currentItemID;
    if (confirm(ctx.RecycleBinEnabled ? Strings.STS.L_STSRecycleConfirm_Text : Strings.STS.L_STSDelConfirm_Text)) {
        SubmitFormPost(ctx.HttpPath + "&Cmd=Delete&List=" + ctx.listName + "&ID=" + ciid + "&NextUsing=" + GetSource());
    }
}

}
```

you can create your custom menuin the javascript function Custom_AddListMenuItems